# Alamofire extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I use `Alamofire` 4.0.1 and have this code:

```
let params = Mapper().toJSON(group)

Alamofire.request("\(Config().apiAdminTableGroup)\(group.id)/", method: .put, parameters: params, headers: Config().apiHeaders, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        ...
}
```

But getting this error:

> Extra argument 'method' in call

This is by documentation, is this bug or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the structure of your `parameters` and `headers` are right, if not the error you mentioned appears. It should look like that:

```
Alamofire.request("\(Config().apiAdminTableGroup)\(group.id)/", method: .put, parameters: ["param1":"1", "param2":"2"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization": "Basic xxx"])
```

Comment: I have used 'Alamofire.request("", method: .POST, parameters: self.postData, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
' still I get the same damn error

Comment: What if you add the `header` parameter? like this: `Alamofire.request("", method: .POST, parameters: self.postData, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON{ response in self.responseData = response.result.value } ` @Siddharth

Comment: same thing.. no change. Btw is it "parameters" or "Parameters" ?

Comment: Its "parameters". Did you check the structure of your paramaters dictionary as I mentioned in the answer?@Siddharth

Comment: if I use `parameters` I get use of undeclared type 'parameters`. If I use `Parameters` I dont get that error. For example `var getData     : parameters` gives an error.

Comment: ok, I just recommend you to ask a new question with mentioning this answer if you want. It seems also that you don't use the newest version of alamofire, because `.POST` is in uppercase. You should also mention the version for better verifying the problem @Siddharth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113651/swift-3-0-alamofire-4-0-extra-argument-method-in-call?noredirect=1#comment71397619_42113651

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.PUT, "\(Config().apiAdminTableGroup)\(group.id)/",
                parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
            ...
    }
```

Comment: This is for alamofire 3, i use 4.0.1.